# Shell script that finds keyword on an index.html file

Tags: shell

I am currently new to shell scripting on Linux. I am trying to create a script that reads for keywords that i choose from a website. For example if my script says find the word apple on food.com the script will read the website and spit out a text file that says the "word exist" if apple is picked up by the script. The problem I am having right now is figuring out what I should wright. I used wget to index.html file and I currently have my if then statement written out but nothing is in it. I was also thinking of using curl or regex to read my html file for the keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way in your bash file:

```
if grep -q yourword yourfile; then
    echo found
else
    echo not found
fi
```

Running grep without `-q` argument returns the match if it founds it and nothing if it not founds it, but when running grep with `-q` it will return `True` if founds it and `False` if not.

Answer (score 0):

The command usually used for finding words in a text is `grep`.
You should definitely have a look at it.

Comment: Thxs let me take a look at grep.